# Интонационное тире или нет?

Tags: тире, авторская-пунктуация

***Читала звонко, стояла – руки по швам, как подчасок у Вечного огня.*** Их так учили. В частной гимназии... была уже совсем другая мода на выразительное чтение: дети трясли головами, размахивали руками и так завывали в логическом конце фразы, как будто изображали ветер. Или волка.

1) **По выделенному предложению**

Тире авторское (интонационное) или нет? Если оно обязательное, то по какому правилу  ставится? ***Подчасок***  – это авторский неологизм или такое слово существует в языке?

2) **По тексту**

Автор ироничен по отношению к обеим манерам чтения?

А как сейчас в школах учат детей выразительно читать стихи?

Или: Как выразительно прочитать стихотворение? Существует ли "мода" на чтение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А. В словаре русского языка:
[ПОДЧА́СОК](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA), *-ска, м. Воен. устар.* Помощник часового на посту.
[В словаре Ушакова пометки "устар." еще нет: ПОДЧАСОК, ска, м. (воен.). Помощник часового на посту. *Пришел городовой, подчаска подозвал* (Некрасов).]

*Правда, посты усиленные, по два человека: часовой и [подчасок](https://books.google.ee/books?id=NhKfMQsDAIEC&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0:%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA.&source=bl&ots=ZiSpdv6vjh&sig=ACfU3U0JgTXEbJu2OygI90jKG6VnFxwDWw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqgPjTobnjAhUV7KYKHRahAlYQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%3A%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA.&f=false).*

B. Думаю, что тире авторское — для выделения, подчеркивания того, *как именно* (плюс нестандартное слово "подчасок") стояла некрасивая тощая девочка ("За шваброй может спрятаться"), пытающаяся с глупой улыбкой (но торжественно) прочитать стихотворение про Ленина.
*Читала звонко, стояла – руки по швам, как подчасок у Вечного огня.*

Без такого подчеркивания тире обычно не ставится:
*Они стояли руки по швам и смотрели на него так, как ему хотелось* (А. и Б. Стругацкие. Возвращение); *Виктор Федорович стоял руки по швам, бледный* (В. Ахинько. Нестор Махно).

C. Ирония, безусловно, присутствует в обоих случаях (мера и здравый смысл должны быть во всем).

D. "Мода" на чтение? Да, наверное. Маяковский, Рождественский, Ахмадулина, Высоцкий — их "манеры чтения" невозможно спутать и практически невозможно повторить-копировать.
Нет, наверное. "Ляписы-Трубецкие" и "папа у Васи силен в математике" были и будут всегда.

**Дополнение**

*Что касается "подчаска", такое слово не употреблялось при воспитании юных пионеров...*
Употреблялось.

1. Пост №1 г. Волгограда.
   Автор — заместитель директора по воспитательной работе МОУ СОШ № 20 Барабанова С.В., [подчасок 1986 года](http://post1.volgadmin.ru/09.htm).
   Автор — педагог-организатор МОУ Центра «Пост №1» Бесперстова Елена Владимировна, подчасок 1978 года.
2. [1979 год] *Из дома через двор до арки мы шли гурьбой, выйдя из арки на ул. Цвиллинга,  уже строевым шагом. Часовыми назывались стоящие возле Вечного огня, стоящие рядом с ними — подчасками. [Подчасок](https://ov68.livejournal.com/4335.html) — это юнармеец, поддерживающий общественный порядок на Посту №1 и у Вечного Огня. Подчаски назначались педсоветом своей школы, лицея, гимназии, из числа девочек. Часовые — мальчики. Подчаски следуют на Пост №1 вместе с часовыми и с ними же сменяются. Одеты строго по форме, с повязкой на рукаве.*

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и информацию. А я-то думала, что подчасок - это неологизм, интересная находка автора, так хорошо слово вписалось в текст. Даже разочаровалась немного. Манеры чтения, конечно, бывают разные, но интересно, есть ли мода на чтение, как на одежду, например.  Руки по швам - устойчивое выражение, связь примыкание, ведь глагол им не управляет? Только в этом случае тире интонационное (необязательное). Кстати, девочка после 7-го класса превратилась в красавицу, которой постоянно завидовала главная героиня (а текст написан в форме воспоминаний).

Answer (score 1):

Тире здесь *авторское*: для устойчивых выражений о стоянии "руки в боки" или "руки по швам" отделение знаками не требуется, если судить по книгам ( = по корректорской практике). Однако неясно, чем именно автор руководствовался, интонацией или интуицией. В доброй половине книжных источников авторы словно сознательно избегают промежутка между "стоянием" и его характеристикой, добавляя "вытянув" или иные разбивающие сочетание слова и фразы, требующие постановки запятой или тире, - просто чтобы не промахнуться с пунктуацией. Тире можно поставить и на основании опущения такого подразумеваемого "вытянув", и от этого не будет ошибки (т. е. корректору не нужно вмешиваться). Так или иначе, с паузой наш текст читается хуже, чем без неё. Поэтому тире выглядит поставленным "на всякий случай". В сочетании *так... как будто* лишним кажется одно из слов *так/как*.

Ирония автора, возможно, направлена на потуги образовательных учреждений прививать детям какую-нибудь идеологию: в государственных - подобострастие в форме военного патриотизма, в частных - свободолюбие. Результаты воздействия подсознательно проявляются в манере чтения.

Что касается "подчаска", такое слово *не* употреблялось при воспитании юных пионеров, которые и впрямь время от времени стояли у костров в честь чего-нибудь. Это собственная находка автора, забытое слово употреблено в значении "юный часовой".

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Конечно же,  я не согласна  с оценкой тире в этом тексте, я думаю, что обособляется весь однородный ряд из двух обстоятельств, а интонация параллельная (ударение на читала и стояла).  Я насчет грамматической связи сомневалась - может ли это сочетание примыкать к глаголу. А насчет идеологии я согласна, она в манере чтения отражается, причем у нас любят из одной крайности бросаться в другую - то мы очень дисциплинированные, то очень свободные и раскованные. Интересно, сейчас-то мы какие, можно ли по  декламации определить?